# Modelling the shape, volume, and the surface area of a shampoo bottle.

Tags: integration, volume, surfaces

*I want to model the volume and the surface area of the object that can be seen in the images below.*

[Front view of Bottle 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmAP1.jpg)

[Side view of Bottle 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0jEV.jpg)

[Front view of Bottle 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mmp4.jpg)

[Side view of Bottle 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvm0Q.jpg)

I realize that the objects (Shampoo and body wash bottles) are irregular and that I don't know their cross-sections at regular intervals. I don't have any equations for them. So, I reckon that the simple methods of integration cannot be employed. I was wondering if it is possible to model these bottles, somehow? I have heard software like GeoGebra and Logger Pro make it possible such modeling and volumetric analysis of irregular shapes. I have tried searching on the web, but am thoroughly confused.

I am simply looking for suggestions that can guide me on how I should proceed with this problem, and I am not looking for exact solutions.

**P.S** - I am not very proficient in mathematics, and am pursuing this project as a self-challenge project at high-school level.

Any kind of help, feedback, or suggestions is welcome!

Spare me if I have overlooked something very obvious. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: Can I just simply paste the picture in logger pro, plot points along the boundary of the object, and do a curve fit. After the curve fit is predicted, I can simply revolve it around an axis to get an approximation.

**Edit 2:** The drawback of this method is that the approximation would be far from accurate as the shampoo bottles are far from being perfectly circular objects and so integrating solids of revolution method is not a good option. Any thoughts on the same?

Comment: I want to be able to mathematically describe the shape of the bottle and _"model"_ its volume, and surface area, and not just _calculate_. I know it's very easy to calculate. I could have just emptied the shampoo bottles and measured the amount of water that they hold. But there is no challenge in that. @ThomasRot

Comment: A little clarification: you want to do it with pen and paper, or you want to write a computer program that can do it? Also, should it work from a couple of pictures, or are you "allowed" to do your own measurements?

Comment: For 3D surface approximation see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface

Comment: Firstly, thank you @YuriyS for helping me out. I am willing to write a computer program if required. I am also allowed to do my own measurements. Found this paper  [link] (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4788/dfa593ffacbec36c7dbb5800173715894029.pdf) that uses silhouette cross-section of images of the object at different angles and then combines them to reconstruct the 3d object. It's pretty interesting!! In fact, it is also a plausible solution to our problem, however, the problem is that the software they have used is paid, and I don't have access to it. Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: @AdityaGarg, well, this seems like a great method, why don't you try using it (if it's not too hard to implement of course). I think section 3.3. goes into enough detail on the formulas

Comment: @YuriyS Access to the software is the issue. I can't afford to buy the software, and it seems difficult to reconstruct the 3d figure without it. Though, I feel still optimistic about this silhouette method. I am still trying to look for other ways to reconstruct the object, using cross-sections but without the software.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me where and how can I plot the silhouette of an object from an image? Like some graphing software or something. And how can I integrate multiple sets of plots of silhouettes to reconstruct a 3D model? This can help me recreate the object and calculate the volume and the surface area.